# twitter-bootstrap-rails gem not displaying the proper image icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap

After building my rails application and testing it all on both development and production environment, every thing works just fine.

But after deploying the application, the whole icons just stoped working. I tried it on my mobile devise and I started to see different types of icons which was not what I specifies. After about 24hrs, the whole icons stopped working on my mobile devise.

For clearea and better understanding, you can check out the site hosted at www.dep.rzaartz.com/profiles/1 you will see what I am talking about. Am I doing anything wrong or what can I do to fix this?

I am using the latest twitter-bootstrap-rails gem and rails 3.2.6.

Comment: All the icons in that site you linked worked fine for me.

Comment: Did they represent what it was actuall talking. Like the photos lik an the nav bar does it display a camera beside it and does the elibrary have a book icon beside it?

Comment: It works well on the web browser but does not work on my bb devise. I wonder it is because of the `<i>`  tag.

Comment: Not displaying the images on blackerry mobile devises

Comment: Not displaying the images on blackerry mobile devises

Answer (score 2):

You must change `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less`:

```
* `@fontAwesomeEotPath:  'fontawesome-webfont.eot';`
* `@fontAwesomeWoffPath: 'fontawesome-webfont.woff';`
* `@fontAwesomeTtfPath:  'fontawesome-webfont.ttf';`
* `@fontAwesomeSvgzPath: 'fontawesome-webfont.svgz';`
* `@fontAwesomeSvgPath:  'fontawesome-webfont.svg';`
```

After this you must execute:

```
`bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace`
```